# Remove quotes from variable push

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm taking the data I get back from an AJAX query and doing this:

```
var chart_d=[];    
chart_d.push('['+index+","+item.count+']');
```

The result is this.

```
["[0,2860]", "[1,4858]", "[2,12735]", "[3,11432]", "[4,23950]", "[5,1002970]"]
```

However, what I need is this:

```
 [[0,2860], [1,4858], [2,12735], [3,11432], [4,23950], [5,1002970]]
```

That is, the same exact thing, but without all the double quotes. I'm not sure how those get added in.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried: `chart_d.push([index,item.count]);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
chart_d.push([index, item.count]);
```